# Emmiting Data from one component to another Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is my Table component.

```
<b-table
    class="table table-striped"
      id="my-table"
      :items="items"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      :fields="fields"
      @row-clicked="test"
      lg
    ></b-table>
```

method on the same component:

```
methods: {
    test(){
        console.log('test')
        this.$emit('rowClick',"heyoooooooo")
    }
},
```

parent component:

```
    <ClientTable :fields="fields" :items="rows" :sortBy="sortBy" :sortDesc="sortDesc" @rowClicked="Callme()"/>
```

parent method:

```
methods: {
    Callme(e){
        console.log('hee')
    }
},
```

I'm really new with VueJS and I stumbled with Emit I was wondering why is my code not working, does not console anything.

thanks

Comment: Your table component emits `rowClick` but your parent component subscribes to `@rowClicked`.

Comment: hi sir, tried it, but didnt work `this.$emit('rowClicked',"heyoooooooo")` also added () on test

Comment: Usually I remove the `()`. Are you using [bootstrap vue `b-table`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#comp-ref-b-table-events)? Try `@row-clicked` on your parent component ([kebab-case event names](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names))

Comment: yes, I'm using bootstrap vue table and I want to make rows clickable, the @row-click wont work, changed the emit to row-clicked too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreate your question and it's works well.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('client-table', {
  props: ['items'],
  methods: {
    test(){
      this.$emit('row-clicked',"heyoooooooo")
    }  
  },
  template: `
    <b-table
      class="table table-striped"
      :items="items"            
      lg
      @row-clicked="test"
    ></b-table>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [
      { 'heading 1': 'table cell', 'heading 2': 'table cell', 'heading 3': 'table cell' },
      { 'heading 1': 'table cell', 'heading 2': 'table cell', 'heading 3': 'table cell' },
      { 'heading 1': 'table cell', 'heading 2': 'table cell', 'heading 3': 'table cell' },
    ]
  },  
  methods: {
   Callme (e) {
       console.log(e)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link
  type="text/css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  />
<link
  type="text/css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"
  />

<div id="app">
  <client-table 
    :items="rows"
    @row-clicked="Callme">
  </client-table>
</div>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.28/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this too. didn't work. with and without `()` also

Comment: @cj What didn't work? Nothing to console? Nothing rendered on screen? We need more context

Comment: Hi A1rPun, thanks for the response. It works now. I think the problem was when I git checkout it didn't update my base fille i need to npm run serve it again